# Convert a string from json to Python: Problem

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a Json string, that i got from a Website, to a python string, but it doesent work.

```
import json

y = json.loads({"title":null,"icon":null,"iphoneURL":null,"splitURL":null,"splitPercent":null,"expiresAt":null,"expiredURL":null,"clicksLimit":null,"source":"api","integrationGA":null,"integrationFB":null,"integrationAdroll":null,"integrationGTM":null,"id":,"originalURL":"http://instagramm.com","DomainId":,"archived":false,"path":"","cloaking":null,"redirectType":null,"createdAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","OwnerId":,"updatedAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","secureShortURL":"","idString":"lnk_X1P_RGeQY","shortURL":"","duplicate":false})

print(y["originalURL"])
```

As far as I can tell, I am missing some ' in front and back of the JSON string, but I have no idea, how to add them.

Sorry for my bad English and python Skills

Edit: ive tried adding ' with comma, + and .join ('"""')

Edit2:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.short.io/links/xxxxxx"
wurl = "youtube.com"

response = requests.request("POST", url, json={"allowDuplicates": False, "domain": "1cr0.short.gy", "originalURL": wurl}, headers={"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"})

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the json string an actual sting. So try putting single quotes around it. Like so:

```py
import json

y = json.loads('{"title":null,"icon":null,"iphoneURL":null,"splitURL":null,"splitPercent":null,"expiresAt":null,"expiredURL":null,"clicksLimit":null,"source":"api","integrationGA":null,"integrationFB":null,"integrationAdroll":null,"integrationGTM":null,"id":793212684,"originalURL":"http://instagramm.com","DomainId":226909,"archived":false,"path":"5n316HkujOzP","cloaking":null,"redirectType":null,"createdAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","OwnerId":221852,"updatedAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","secureShortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","idString":"lnk_X1P_RGeQY","shortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","duplicate":false}')

print(y["originalURL"])
```

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to add them automatically. That's my problem

Comment: I don't understand the question here, sorry. What are you actually receiving? Can you give a more precise example?

Comment: I am getting the string without the quotes, as I put it there, now my problem is, to add quotes automatically in front and in the back, but I don't know, how to.

Comment: The string itself should not include the quotes. They are just denoting the sequence of characters as a string. So if you already receive a `str` try passing this to `json.loads()`

Comment: If you look to my code, that is my string, that's how I got him, but I don't know, how to add quotes, and if I pass it directly through, it gives me an error.

Comment: Did you manually copy and paste it into your python file?

Comment: No, that's automated, but I would still need to add quotes manually if I did it this way, so I need a way, to add quotes automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand you. You are saying an external power automatically puts those characters that form a json object into your python file? I have hard time imagining this. Can you show a bit more of your script?

Comment: sure. look now to the original question, in the second code box, you should see the code, that does the request. if you run it, you should get a (kind of) similar JSON string. I want to convert that to a Python usable sting.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes around your `y` variable to make it a string, I recommend an ide so it can point out stuff like this.

```
y = json.loads('{"title":null,"icon":null,"iphoneURL":null,"splitURL":null,"splitPercent":null,"expiresAt":null,"expiredURL":null,"clicksLimit":null,"source":"api","integrationGA":null,"integrationFB":null,"integrationAdroll":null,"integrationGTM":null,"id":793212684,"originalURL":"http://instagramm.com","DomainId":226909,"archived":false,"path":"5n316HkujOzP","cloaking":null,"redirectType":null,"createdAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","OwnerId":221852,"updatedAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","secureShortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","idString":"lnk_X1P_RGeQY","shortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","duplicate":false}')
```

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to add them. That's my problem

Comment: I have already added them you can copy them

Comment: but automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please pass your json data in a string.

Try:

```
import json

y = json.loads('{"title":null,"icon":null,"iphoneURL":null,"splitURL":null,"splitPercent":null,"expiresAt":null,"expiredURL":null,"clicksLimit":null,"source":"api","integrationGA":null,"integrationFB":null,"integrationAdroll":null,"integrationGTM":null,"id":793212684,"originalURL":"http://instagramm.com","DomainId":226909,"archived":false,"path":"5n316HkujOzP","cloaking":null,"redirectType":null,"createdAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","OwnerId":221852,"updatedAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","secureShortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","idString":"lnk_X1P_RGeQY","shortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","duplicate":false}')

print(y["originalURL"])
```

Output:

```
http://instagramm.com
```

Comment: I know, but i don't know, how to add them automatically, that's my problem.

Comment: There's nothing that can be done automatically, you have to get it done by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a **JSON String** to `json.loads()`. You are just passing the JSON as is (*Not a string*).

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

> `json.loads(s)` - *Deserialize s (a **str**, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document)*

```
import json

y = json.loads('{"title":null,"icon":null,"iphoneURL":null,"splitURL":null,"splitPercent":null,"expiresAt":null,"expiredURL":null,"clicksLimit":null,"source":"api","integrationGA":null,"integrationFB":null,"integrationAdroll":null,"integrationGTM":null,"id":793212684,"originalURL":"http://instagramm.com","DomainId":226909,"archived":false,"path":"5n316HkujOzP","cloaking":null,"redirectType":null,"createdAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","OwnerId":221852,"updatedAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","secureShortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","idString":"lnk_X1P_RGeQY","shortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","duplicate":false}')

print(y["originalURL"])
```

```
http://instagramm.com
```

Comment: I know, but i don't know, how to add them automatically, that's my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *automatically* ? Put your JSON in between single quotes- ```'JSON'```. Is your JSON stored in any variable ?

Comment: yes, but can´t python do that for me? I am getting these strings relatively often, and I don't want to add quotes every single time.

Comment: If you have the JSON stored in a variable, you don't need to add any quotes. You can just do ```json.loads(x)``` - ```x``` is the variable containing JSON. If you want more clarity, I suggest you clearly mention (in your question from where you are getting that JSON. Is it an API/file etc.,) what your problem is so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
import json

```
y = '''{"title":null,"icon":null,"iphoneURL":null,"splitURL":null,"splitPercent":null,"expiresAt":null,"expiredURL":null,"clicksLimit":null,"source":"api","integrationGA":null,"integrationFB":null,"integrationAdroll":null,"integrationGTM":null,"id":793212684,"originalURL":"http://instagramm.com","DomainId":226909,"archived":false,"path":"5n316HkujOzP","cloaking":null,"redirectType":null,"createdAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","OwnerId":221852,"updatedAt":"2021-08-03T17:02:20.935Z","secureShortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","idString":"lnk_X1P_RGeQY","shortURL":"https://1cr0.short.gy/5n316HkujOzP","duplicate":false}'''

y = json.loads(y)

print(y["originalURL"])
```

I just converted the json to string before loading

Answer (score 0):

print(response.text)

You can save the return of this code into a variable.

```
var = str(response.text)
y = json.loads(var)

print(y["originalURL"])
```

and type cast it into a string before passing it into the variable.

Comment: OMG, Thx! that's exactly, what i was looking for, tywm!

Comment: Do upvote and mark it as a correct answer!

Comment: cant, too les carma

Comment: That's actually sad :p